# tc don't see marked with -j MARK packets

Tags: linux, iptables, tc

Server has 2 network interfaces:

- eth1 with address 13.0.0.254/24
- eth0 with address 172.20.203.4/24.

It's routing traffic between this two networks. Task is to limit bandwidth between this two networks to 1Vbit/sec, but not to limit bandwidth between server and network hosts(i. e. limit all packets going though FORWARD)

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 13.0.0.0/24 -d 172.20.203.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x0001
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.203.0/24 -d 13.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x0002

# eth1
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1:0 htb default 2

tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 999mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 1mbps

tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 2:0 sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:3 handle 3:0 sfq perturb 10

tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 handle 1 fw flowid 1:3
tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 handle 2 fw flowid 1:3

# eth0
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb default 2

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 999mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 1mbps

tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 2:0 sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3 handle 3:0 sfq perturb 10

tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 handle 2 fw flowid 1:3
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 handle 1 fw flowid 1:3
```

This doesn't work. If I use this at the beginning:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1:0 htb default 3
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb default 3
```

it works. So problem is in filter settings.

```
iptables -L -v -n -t mangle
```

shows, that packets are going though MARK rules. I tried to mark packets not in POSTROUTING, but in FORWARD or PREROUTING - this does not work too. What am I doing wrong?

Here is some diagnostics:

```
# tc -s -d -r filter show dev eth0
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw handle 0x1 classid 1:3
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw handle 0x2 classid 1:3
# tc -s -d -r filter show dev eth1
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw handle 0x2 classid 1:3
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw handle 0x1 classid 1:3
```

Kernel config:

```
/boot # uname -a
Linux armada-sc-02 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/boot # grep CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES config-2.6.32-5-amd64
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y
/boot # grep CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER config-2.6.32-5-amd64
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y
/boot # grep CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_FWMARK config-2.6.32-5-amd64
```

Comment: Is the Linux kernel configured with `fwmark` support?  Per http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html you need `CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER`, `CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES` and `CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_FWMARK`.

Comment: Updated question. There is no CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_FWMARK line in kernel conifig. May be for 2.6.32 it does not exist anymore?

Comment: Try `grep IP_NF /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64`, `grep NETFILTER /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64`, `grep CONNMARK /boot/config-2.6.32-5-amd64`.  I'm not sure what the exact option would be, but from reading it appears that things have changed since `2.6.20`.  In `3.5` it's `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MARK`.

Comment: `modprobe xt_mark` helped. Thank you very much! Write an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I wrote up an answer.  Feel free to add any edits you like and I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing with the `MARK` `IPTABLES` target not working as expected was caused by a missing kernel module which enables that specific [Netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/) functionality.  In order to use the `MARK` target, you need to load the `XT_MARK` module which must be compiled with the Linux kernel.

Check your kernel config for `CONFIG_NETFILTER_...` items and ensure that `...XT_MARK` and its prerequisites are compiled.  If the `XT_MARK` item was compiled as a module, you'll need to load it with `modprobe xt_mark`.